# Gem::RemoteSourceException with rubygems 0.9.0

Tags: ruby, rubygems

This Perl expert likes ruby OK, but I'm having trouble with a legacy ruby environment I have to maintain.

One host I am maintaining has rubygems 0.9.0, and I can't get it to access a remote repository for an upgrade:

```
$ gem list --remote --source 'http://rubygems.org/' 

*** REMOTE GEMS ***
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteSourceException)
    HTTP Response 302
```

Apparently this old version can't follow a redirect, and doesn't tell me where it wants to redirect.

Can someone supply:

- The correct source repository?

or

- How to manually get a newer version of rubygems installed?

Answer (score 0):

From http://rubygems.org/pages/download:

```
gem install rubygems-update
update_rubygems
```

Comment: Sorry, I get the same response to 'gem install rubygems-update' - the bigger problem is actually not be able to install any gems.